# cx oracle ImportError

Tags: oracle, macos, python-2.7

I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/julia3/768474fee38926f63768) for installing cx_oracle on Mac. After some tweaks it was successful. I was using Mavericks earlier. Then I got an **upgrade to El Capitan**. That's where the disaster came in.

It stopped working. I couldn't find related files in the directory earlier. Due to [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899), I go through the whole process again and installed this at `usr/local/lib/share/oracle/installclient_11_2`.

But now when I run the program. It throws this error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried a lot of solutions online, like https://gist.github.com/rmoff/5a70862f27d2284e9541, http://kevindalias.com/2014/03/26/how-to-set-up-cx_oracle-for-python-on-mac-os-x-10-89/

Still no luck on me:(

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

==========================================================================

**UPDATE:**

Found [this post](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/oracle/install-cx_oracle-mac) online, works magically on **El Capitan**. Delete the old install, start fresh following this intruction step-by-step.

Comment: @AlexPoole I think so. I use the following command: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is related to the [system integrity protection (SIP) changes in El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899), which among other things prevents DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being inherited by [spawned processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616185/266304).

You can modify the `cx_Oracle.so` library to use the actual path to the Oracle client library instead of the searched path that no longer works; make sure you have `ORACLE_HOME` still set to point to your actual instant client location, and also note that the exact path reported by `ImportError` should be used - the `3071542110` value may vary depending on the version/build of Instant Client you have installed:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/lib/share/oracle/installclient_11_2

install_name_tool -change \
  /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 \
  $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 \
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so
```

... but then that library can't find another Oracle one:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/installclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
  Reason: image not found
```

So you'd need to change that library too, which you may be less comfortable with:

```
install_name_tool -change \
  /ade/b/3071542110/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib \
  $ORACLE_HOME/libnnz11.dylib \
  $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
```

Depending on the exact client version/build you may need to make the file writable before running that command, with:

```
chmod 755 $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
```

With those changes I can run the `cx_Oracle` tests on El Capitan.

More into on `install_name_change` [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac).

---

It looks like the 12c instant client has been built in a way that avoids this issue, so upgrading to that is gong to be simpler than hacking around int he 11g files.

Comment: It's been very nice of you, Alex. 
I tried to reinstall the whole thing(make sure everything is 64-bit). When I run the project, it got an ImportError: `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so, 2): Library not loaded: /ade/dosulliv_ldapmac/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1`

I modified the commands that modify the cx_Oracle.so library to use the actual path. The second command leads to:

Comment: `error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open input file: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 for writing (Permission denied)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't lseek to offset: 0 in file: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 for writing (Bad file descriptor)
`

Comment: `error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't write new headers in file: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 (Bad file descriptor)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't close written on input file: /usr/local/lib/share/oracle/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 (Bad file descriptor)`

Comment: OK, you have the 11.2.0.4 instant client now; which is fine but that seems to be built with different permissions. Just `chmod 755 libclntsh.dylib.11.1` before running the second step.

Comment: Seem almost there. Now when I run the project. I didn't got an ImportError. It's `cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
` Does it have anything to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar?

Comment: No idea, sorry. The tests work for me, I don't have any knowledge beyond that. I'd guess your project is looking for credentials or a TNS alias or something. [From here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13589683/266304) did you export ORACLE_HOME? Maybe your project needs to set that too. Good luck. Also please see if you can delete some of these comments as they should mostly be redundant now.

Comment: I followed the same procedure with install_name_tool and got the same error: cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Comment: @Eric - as with Julia, this haas solved the original issue and it looks like a project or environment set-up problem, maybe. If you can't figure it out you should ask a new question specifically about that.

Answer (score -1):

sample fix with

```
ln -s /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
```