# Vim dyld_library_path

Tags: oracle, bash, vim, sqlplus, instantclient

I setup Oracle instant client (11.2.0.4) on my "El Capitan" OS X to use sqlplus and VORAX on VIM as IDE.

From the bash is all right, I can connect to my DB with sqlplus without problem.

When I open VIM and try to exececute "!sqlplus" I've the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /ade/dosulliv_sqlplus_mac/oracle/sqlplus/lib/libsqlplus.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin/sqlplus
  Reason: image not found

Command terminated
```

It seems a problem with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, and infact if I type a "!Echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" from VIM its empty.

The variable is set, here the output of the same echo from the bash.

```
_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/lib
```

Comment: Did you try exporting it?

Comment: Sounds like are hitting [this issue with system integrity protection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35268217/266304).

Comment: Could you try Instant client 12.1.0.2, which was released a few days ago. It supports El Capitan.